# Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$0jI 669g6n8or' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand why this error is coming. When I am checking in local this error is not there but when I am deploying in cloud this error is showing.

Comment: post your code please?

Comment: something is `null` that shouldn't be